# NSURL Connection Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tcp, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I am using the Wikitude plugin on iOS for AR and I am getting the following errors. Sometimes it will run then other times it will just keep loading. When it does run it gives the errors but everything functions perfect. The code that loads the view is the following:

```
 self.architectWorldNavigation = [self.architectView loadArchitectWorldFromURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"files"]];
```

I am not sure what could be causing this, sometimes disconnecting from wifi works.

Cheers,

Curtis

> 2018-02-12 13:00:39.326356+0000 UAReloaded[5763:2125598]
>   NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100 2018-02-12
>   13:00:40.743844+0000 UAReloaded[5763:2125632] TIC TCP Conn Failed
>   [1:0x1d01654c0]: 1:61 Err(61) 2018-02-12 13:00:40.743939+0000
>   UAReloaded[5763:2125632] Task
>   .<0> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -1004 [1:61]) 2018-02-12 13:00:40.744102+0000
>   UAReloaded[5763:2125594] NSURLConnection finished with error - code
>   -1004